# Как разделить стили для iPad.pro и нетбука с одинаковым разрешением экрана?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, media-queries

В сайте на `wordpress` внутри функции используется в проверка `wp_is_mobile()`, которая проверяет мобильное ли это устройство. У меня есть задача разделить `css` стили для мобильных устройств включая айпады про с разрешением `1024` и нетбуки, начиная с 10ки, у которых тоже разрешение `1024`.
Как это правильно сделать? Вот такая запись обращается только к мобильным устройствам или нетбуки тоже затронет?

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать `orientation`. Например

```
media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Comment: а при перевороте экрана все пофиксится?

Comment: на поворот можно использовать либо те же стили, либо другие. В зависимости от ситуации. У нетбука нет такого свойства, поэтому стили будут работать только для мобильных устройств

Comment: мне вот эта статья помогла https://htmlweb.ru/css/media_screen.php

Answer (score 3):

> Как это правильно сделать?

Определять [user-agent](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) и в зависимости от этого подключать нужный css-файл. `wp_is_mobile()` для этого не подойдет.

Comment: в смысле? `wp_is_mobile()` в `php` отлично справляется. я спрашиваю - можно ли стили разделить с помощью меда-запросов наподобие тех, что выше привел и если нет, то почему

Comment: wp_is_mobile() не делает различий между разными моб. девайсами.  Я так понял то нужно ж именно по разным выдать разный css. Или я не правильно понял?

Comment: нее, забудьте про wp_is_mobile(). Вот передо мной столько `css` файл со стилями - мне нужно мобильным устройствам, размером 1024 пикселя(айпад про) присвоить стили, которые не затронут десктоп размером 1024 пикслеля. есть различные виды записей медиа запросов `@media` - вот я и интересуюсь можно ли ими разделить стили

Comment: У [@media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media) не всё хорошо с определением устройств. С его помощью определяется размеры **окна** браузера. И это совсем не тоже самое, что определение устройства. Более того  парадигме [mobilefirst](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD#.D0.A1.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B8.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.28.C2.ABMobile_first.C2.BB.29) не для всего его можно/стоит использовать.

Comment: т.е. в данном случае решения как такового и нет, с помощью стилей это не отловить? зачем же тогда используются атрибуты `only screen` `max-device-width`

Comment: Именно так, только user-agent в javascript. Ничего другого.

Comment: @Вася `max-device-width` и тд - для определение окна браузера. Это НЕ размеры экрана устройства и тем более не его (устройсва) определение.Определение девайса может быть только по его юзер-агенту. И то клиент его может подделывать :) .

Comment: @SeVlad еще как может. Например, в devtools в Хроме можно поставить любой user-agent

Comment: @KAGGDesign так я ж за то и говорю :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла вот эта [статья](https://htmlweb.ru/css/media_screen.php), а именно использование стилей

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {}
```

сразу после задания для всех устройств

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

а через `js` вот так

```js
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
if (isiPad) {
  document.getElementById("box").style = "background-color:green;";
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

[фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/2t5zv7dp/)